# How to remove the hyperlink from \homepage{}

Tags: hyperlink

I have to submit my resume through a portal but it doesnt accept the document if it has a hyperlink. How do remove the hyperlink from appearing in 
`\homepage(something.github.io)`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a minimal, but compilable code example to help us help you.

Comment: What class are you using? Maybe `moderncv`?

Comment: Yes, I am using moderncv.

Answer (score 1):

You can type the homepage URL in verbatim mode.

For example:

```
\begin{verbatim}
https://tex.stackexchange.com
\end{verbatim}
```

or shortly

```
\verb|https://tex.stackexchange.com|
```